# I am getting issue with sorting order in SQL Server while it is correct order in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with xyz as (select '301_3' as a  union select '30_3' as a ) select a from xyz order by a;
```

Result in SQL Server is

```
30_3  
301_3
```

Same result in oracle is

```
a   
301_3  
30_3
```

Comment: what do you expect when you don't add an order by ? The only way in any database to get the results in the order you want it, is to add an order by clause, it is not because one database happens to display it in the order you want that it will continue to do so if you don't add an order by

Comment: Look at it here, in the order you want [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=38f07bb30f1807331820626e3e60bc7d) but it's no guarantee, if you run it it might return in another order

Comment: btw from dual is need in oracle

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I get the *opposite* sort order when running your code against SQL Server 2019 in a demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ea188ae8ca6986dbd59ef11d7c29fca).  The order we are seeing should basically be treated as random and up to the database to decide.  In general, if you want a certain order, you should add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

To generate the output you are seeing in Oracle, sort descending:

```sql
WITH xyz AS (
    SELECT '301_3' AS a  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '30_3'
)

SELECT a 
FROM xyz
ORDER BY a DESC;
```

Comment: with xyz as (select '301_3' as a  union select '30_3' as a ) select a from xyz order by a ; please check and run this , this query is placed in already existed java object , does it possible to change without collation effect

Comment: Yes, you may iterate the result set in reverse from Java.